# ComboBox binding - receive notification on ComboBox item change

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I want to display a list of `ComboBoxes`, each `ComboBox` gets its master list from its parent `DataContext` but its value is bound to list that drives the list of `ComboBoxes`

Essentially I have a master list of items (`AvailableRegisters`).  I then display a list of ComboBoxes which basically equate to the currently selected `Register`s

**What works**

- I can see the correct number of ComboBoxes per `SelectedRegisters`

**What doesnt work**

- When I select another item from the combobox I do not receive a `CollectionChanged` event

**ViewModel Code:** 
Here is my (shortened) `ViewModel` code

```
public class DialogViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<IOViewModel> InputOutputList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<AvailableRegister> AvailableRegisters { get; set; }
}

public class IOViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<AvailableRegister> SelectedRegisters { get; set; }

    public IOViewModel()
    {
        this.Registers = new ObservableCollection<AvailableRegister>();
        this.Registers.CollectionChanged += Registers_CollectionChanged;
    }

    void Registers_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Never hit when changing combo box
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="4" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedRegisters, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"></ItemsControl>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
    <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AvailableRegisters, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate><!-- Display it here --></DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are only selecting an item from the `ComboBox` from your ObservableCollection. You aren't changing the collection itself.

If you want, create a property on your `ViewModel` called `SelectedItem` then bind your SelectedItem to it.

```
public class IOViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<AvailableRegister> SelectedRegisters { get; set; }

    private AvailableRegister _selectedRegister;
    public AvailableRegister SelectedRegister { get { return _selectedRegister; } set { _selectedRegister = value; } }

    public IOViewModel()
    {
        this.Registers = new ObservableCollection<AvailableRegister>();
        this.Registers.CollectionChanged += Registers_CollectionChanged;
    }

    void Registers_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Never hit when changing combo box
    }
}
```

---

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AvailableRegisters, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate><!-- Display it here --></DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Not sure I follow, could you put it into context with my `ViewModel` names? Thanks

Comment: @Chris I've edited it. May need a little twerking. The idea is when you select an item from the combobox, you'll see it get set in the set method of SelectedItem on your ViewModel.

Comment: I need a list of `SelectedRegisters` not just one. Hence the `ObservableCollection`.  I display a list of `ComboBox` based on that `ObservableCollection`